# Pandas: Applying filter function on column which type is a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, apply

So my problem is that, I have created DF with column ('Interval_range'), that zips values from two other columns('Start_interval and 'End_interval')  and creates third one (Interval_range'), which type is a list. Now, I woluld like to create fourth one ('Absolute_frequency'), that counts all the values from the external list ('dataset'), which are bigger than first argument of 'Interval_range' column, and less than second argument of 'Interval_range' column. How can I do that? I was trying to use .apply() and then filter() but finally i got nothing. Here is all my code:

```
dataset= [8,30,30,50,86,94,102,110,169,170,176,236,240,241,242,255,262,276,279,282]

interval = (max(dataset)-min(dataset))/6

int1 = [round(min(dataset),2),round(min(dataset)+interval,2)]
int2= [round(int1[1],2),round(int1[1]+interval,2)]
int3 =[round(int2[1],2),round(int2[1]+interval,2)]
int4 =[round(int3[1],2),round(int3[1]+interval,2)]
int5 =[round(int4[1],2),round(int4[1]+interval,2)]
int6 =[round(int5[1],2),round(max(dataset),2)]

intervals = [int1,int2,int3,int4,int5,int6]

analiza = pd.DataFrame(intervals,index='A B C D E F'.split(),columns='Start_interval End_interval'.split())
analiza['Interval_range'] = list(zip(analiza['Start_interval'],analiza['End_interval']))
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you convert `dataset` to `numpy` array you can iterate over `'Interval_range'` column and check if the value s in the range of the tuples using `apply()` and `lambda` expression

```
dataset = [8, 30, 30, 50, 86, 94, 102, 110, 169, 170, 176, 236, 240, 241, 242, 255, 262, 276, 279, 282]
arr = np.array(dataset)
....
analiza['Absolute_frequency'] = analiza['Interval_range'].apply(lambda x: ((x[0] <= arr) & (arr <= x[1])).sum())
```

Output

```
   Start_interval  End_interval    Interval_range  Absolute_frequency
A            8.00         53.67      (8.0, 53.67)                   4
B           53.67         99.34    (53.67, 99.34)                   2
C           99.34        145.01   (99.34, 145.01)                   2
D          145.01        190.68  (145.01, 190.68)                   3
E          190.68        236.35  (190.68, 236.35)                   1
F          236.35        282.00   (236.35, 282.0)                   8
```